# Avoid horizontal scrollbars when using margin-left (on an element with 100% width) to show a fixed menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

In my page, there is a fixed menu `td` on the left (doesn't scroll with the page) that is 150px wide. The page container is 100% width. When you used `position:fixed` on an element, it takes the element out of the layout, so you have to work around it to make sure everything can be seen. Because of this, I have `margin-left:150px` set on the page container. This is causing it to overflow 150px off the screen to the right, making a horizontal scroll bar show.

I can't just hide the overflow, because elements need to be centered horizontally, and they would appear too far to the right. I can't calculate it with JavaScript, because the menu is collapsible, so the width would need to be recalculated every time the menu is collapsed. I also can't edit the HTML; I'm redesigning a site with CSS and JavaScript/jQuery.

Here is a demo that will explain my problem better: http://jsfiddle.net/3yBRV/4/embedded/result/

Comment: remove the style `width: 100% !important;` from #page_cont

Comment: @krish: see my comment on Michael's answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. Because the width on the `td` was set to `600` in the attribute, using `width: auto !important` overrode that setting.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `width: 100% !important;` from your cell to get rid of horizontal scroll. Your td element will do the job itself.

Comment: The problem is that the site I am redesigning has `<td width="600">`, so I have to override that.

Comment: You can try javascript `$('td.main_content').width('auto');` or `$('td.main_content').removeAttr('width')`

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the box-model via `box-sizing: border-box`.

http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/